# Why do Rails compiled assets make the layout look different in production mode?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, google-chrome

I am working on a Rails 3.2.1 application with the twitter-bootstrap-rails gem.

When in development mode, the layout looks like I want it to.

But, when I deploy to production and precompile the assets, the layout is bigger and everything is a little skewed.

Note: this is only happening with Google Chrome.

Does anyone have any idea why this is happening?

Comment: Mind uploading screenshots??.. I had a similar problem once!

Comment: Honestly, sounds like Chrome's infamous problem with over-caching of assets. What happens (in both dev mode and prod mode) when you view in Google Chrome in incognito mode?

Comment: @Ben Lee: The same problem is happening in incognito mode as well.

Comment: Okay, then it's not the caching problem I was thinking of.

Comment: Now that I see the screenshots, looks like you're just zoomed in in production. Try Ctrl-0.

Comment: @Ben Lee:  That solved the problem.  Thanks!  A little embarassing. I'm curious why I was zoomed in while viewing the website at the production URL and not at the development URL?  Does Chrome save my zoom preferences for all the different websites I view?

Comment: @groffcole, yes it does save them. Posted an answer.

Comment: I deleted the comment with the screen shots for project security reasons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is your browser is zoomed in on the production server.

Google Chrome permanently saves zoom preferences based on the hostname.

You can return to the default zoom level by pressing `Ctrl-0` or `⌘-0`.